# Make initialization variables accessible to several attributes initialization methods

Tags: c++

I write a class using sparse matrices. It happens that for both of them, their non-zeros are on the same (i,j)s. As I have to compute these (i,j)s, I'd prefer to have to do it only once.

Currently, I do it separately and my constructor looks like this:

```
class C
{
    private:
        matrix matA;
        matrix matA;
        holder ijs;

    private:
        matrix initMatA();
        matrix initMatA();
        holder init_ijs(int, int);

    public:
        C(int, int);
};

C::C(int foo, int bar) : init_ijs(foo, bar), matA(initMatA()), matB(initMatB())
{
}
```

as I've read that it is best practice to use initialization list (and actually, when I first wrote it, if I remember correctly it was impossible to instantiate my matrices otherwise *(EDIT: a default constructor seems to fix it?)*).
If it was Python, I could write something like

```
def initMats(foo, bar):
    ...
    return matA, matB
```

If think the C++ way would be something like

```
void initMats(int foo, int bar, matrix &matA, matrix &matB)
{
    ...
}
```

but I guess I cannot pass reference to objects that have not yet been constructed.
Any clue on a way to solve this? My idea was to first create the (i,j)s list as an attribute to my class so I can later use it in my initA and initB methods, but I will not be needing it afterward I don't think it's the best way to do.

Comment: Initialization list is constructing object one after the other. One option would be to store these i,j first, building your two objects and freeing the temp object afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init methods are not idiomatic in C++. Use constructors.

You can achieve what you want with a *delegating constructor* (C++11 and newer). First, you need a constructor for the `matrix` class that accepts an (i,j)-list.

```
  using ijlist = ...; //probably some kind of an array
  class matrix {
      ...
      matrix(const ijlist& ijs) { ... }
      ...
  };
```

Then you write a constructor for `C` that accepts an ijlist and passes it to the two matrix data members:

```
  class C {
      ...
      matrix matA, matB;
      ...
      C(const ijlist& ijs) : matA(ijs), matB(ijs) { ... }
```

Now you can compute your (i,j)-list in an auxiliary function and pass it to this constructor from any other constructor:

```
  C() : C(compute_ijs()) { ... }
```

Comment: I did what I had to do in the constructor; code runs faster and is (from my point of view) easier to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to:

- take two sparse matricies (or similar) as inputs
- compute IJ for the two matricies
- apply IJ to them both before continuing
- construct the Class with the modified matricies.

The constraint is that the matricies are not default-constructible.

I think I would do it something like this:

```
// A class to hold the result of computing ij
struct ij_holder
{
    // whatever goes here
};

// a sparse matrix class
struct sparse_matrix
{
    // let's say it's not default-constructible
    sparse_matrix(int, int , int , int);
};

// apply ij to sparse matrix m, returning the modified matrix
sparse_matrix apply(ij_holder const& ij, sparse_matrix m)
{
    // whatever goes here to modify m

    return m;
}

// compute ij from two matricies
ij_holder compute_ij(sparse_matrix const& a, sparse_matrix const& b);


struct Class
{
    // public constructor written in terms of private constructor
    Class(sparse_matrix const& foo, sparse_matrix const& bar)
    : Class (compute_ij(foo, bar), foo, bar)
    {}

private:
    // private constructor
    Class(ij_holder ij, sparse_matrix const& foo, sparse_matrix const& bar)
    : foo_(apply(ij, foo))
    , bar_(apply(ij, bar))
    {}


sparse_matrix foo_;
sparse_matrix bar_;

};
```

Comment: Actually, the matrices are not inputs. They are private attributes of my object. I have edited my bit of code to make it clearer and make it looks more like C++. Of course, my real class is a little more complex and involves more than two int paramters.
I understood that statements inside the constructor's body operate only on constructed object and should be avoided. If my attributes have been default constructed, is it okay to process them inside the constructor's body?

Comment: @Aubergine from the new code you posted it looks as if the deferred constructor route is probably still correct for you. If your matricies can be default constructed then yes it's fine to manipulate them in the constructor. It's not "best practice" but if they are simple value types then in reality there will be no overhead after the optimiser has done its work.